# Should we create our first community wiki because Cortana?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I think one of the best things in the release of Windows Phone 8.1 Developer Preview is Cortana.

It has a lot of ways to respond the user and in many funny ways.

Now we have this question:

[What "funny" questions can Cortana answer?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/3548/what-funny-questions-can-cortana-answer)

I like to know this things but is somewhat against our FAQ.

But I think in this particular case we should just transform it in a community wiki and let the people enjoy.

Answer (score 6):

I read about [What is community wiki](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/) I came accross this line:

> Community wiki should never be used as a get out of jail free pass for joke and fun questions.

And that line linked to the article [joke and fun questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/) and there is stated:

> I think some members of the community have gotten the idea that Stack Overflow is strictly business — unless your question fits our rules exactly to a T, it is absolutely disallowed. That, here on Stack Overflow, we hate “fun”.
>
> **This is not entirely true.**
>
> In my mind, there are three broad guidelines that determine whether a question is appropriate for Stack Overflow:
>
> 1. Does this question match the criteria provided in the Stack Overflow FAQ?
> 2. Is this question accepted by the community, as reflected in upvotes, favorites, views, and answers?
> 3. Does this question teach me anything that could make me better at my job? Can I learn something from it?
>
> ...
>
> On Stack Overflow, contrary to popular opinion, we don’t hate fun. But only a certain amount of fun will be tolerated

So if I can vote **I vote for leaving that question as is**. That means **no community wiki** and **no closing**.

(for better formatting the answers one can use (suggest) EDIT)

Comment: Yeah, so obviously 2 & 3 are applicable to the Cortana question.

Comment: Thanks, that was my point.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think converting it to a wiki is a good option. It already has 6 answers that you have to scroll though. Having a single answer would be much better.

Comment: Actually you will end up scrolling too. Since if we merge them they will have the same size.

Comment: Setting community wiki doesn't decrease the number of answers, from what I've seen in the past; and there is a minimum reputation required to edit those posts anyway, which would be less inclusive (after all, it already shows a large number of views)

Comment: Ahh right, I thought it might merge the answers (either automatically or manually).